# ggplot greek letter in label within for loop indices

Tags: ggplot2, label, axis, letter

I need to add the theta greek letter in the x-axis label of this plot(s):

```
var=c("a", "b", "c")

df=data.frame(x=c(1:20),y=c(41:60))

df_plot=list()

for (i in 1:length(var)) {
  
  df_plot[[i]]=ggplot()+
  
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  xlab(paste("theta ", var[i]))

}
```

How can I do it?

If I use `expression()` I get the letter but not the index i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bquote` you could do:

Note: Instead of using a `for` loop I switched to `lapply` (and would suggest to so) as sooner or later you will run in issues related to tidy evaluation when using a `for` loop with `ggplot`. And there are plenty of questions on SO related to that. (:

```r
var <- c("a", "b", "c")

df <- data.frame(x = c(1:20), y = c(41:60))

library(ggplot2)

lapply(var, function(x) {
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    xlab(bquote(theta*.(x)))
})
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the index letter does not need to be a subscript..

Comment: Aw. Okay. But that's not a big deal. Maybe `bquote(theta*.(x))` is waht you are looking  for, i.e. that will will give a theta smybol followerd by the character a, b or c.

Comment: that does not work

Comment: I just made an edit with my proposed change.